# Karate-robot error : com.intuit.karate.StringUtils.split(Ljava/lang/String;CZ)Ljava/util/List;

Tags: karate, intuit-partner-platform

I am trying to upload file to a vaadin-upload component using karate-robot and getting this error:
com.intuit.karate.StringUtils.split(Ljava/lang/String;CZ)Ljava/util/List;

Here is the message in log:

```
16:46:14.443 [1618271174442] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - command: [osascript, -e,     tell application "System Events"
    set procs to (processes whose background only is false)
    set results to {}
    repeat with n from 1 to the length of procs
      set p to item n of procs
      set entry to { name of p as text,"|"}
      set end of results to entry
    end repeat
  end tell
  results]
16:46:15.240 [1618271174442] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - Safari, |, Google Chrome, |, Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client, |, Microsoft Outlook, |, BlueJeans, |, Terminal, |, TextEdit, |, BBEdit, |, Notes, |, Calendar, |, idea, |, Microsoft Excel, |, Microsoft PowerPoint, |, Microsoft Word, |, Postman, |, Finder, |, Mattermost, |, Electron, |, Teams, |, Spotify, |, firefox-bin, |, java, |
16:46:15.242 [1618271174442] DEBUG com.intuit.karate.shell.Command - command complete, exit code: 0 - [osascript, -e,     tell application "System Events"
    set procs to (processes whose background only is false)
    set results to {}
    repeat with n from 1 to the length of procs
      set p to item n of procs
      set entry to { name of p as text,"|"}
      set end of results to entry
    end repeat
  end tell
  results]
```

I am trying to run this on vscode in Mac. Here's the feature file data:

```
Feature:   
Background:
    * configure driver = { type: 'chrome', headless: false  } 
    * configure afterFeature = function(){ karate.write({ id: jamaId, errorMessage: karate.info.errorMessage }, 'jama-id-' + jamaId + '.json'); }
    * call read('runsetup/ui_login.feature')
  
Scenario: Verify UI: Default Regulatory Mode Filter to IVD
    * click("{}Applications").delay(1000)
    # * driver.inputFile('#installAppButton', targetDir+"/resources/utilities/ivdDummy1.app")
    * robot { window: '^Chrome', highlight: true }
    # since we have the driver active, the "robot" namespace is needed
    * waitFor('#installAppButton').click().delay(1000)
    * robot.input(targetDir+"/resources/utilities" + Key.ENTER)
    * robot.waitFor('ivdDummy1.app').click()
    * robot.input(Key.ENTER).delay(1000)
    * submit().click('#file-submit')
    * screenshot()
```

Comment: sounds like you have library conflicts. follow this process please: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue